# Generate unique ID for table

Tags: sql, oracle

Let's suppose I have the sample table, but I dropped the *PK* by mistake. I want to regenerate unique ID number and **update the existing (modified) table**.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: Why do you want 1,1,1,2,2,3 and not 1,2,3,4,5,... ?

Comment: Your example is slightly confused, but it sounds like `cat_id` is likely to be a reference to a category table, maybe. Always hard to tell with made-up/obfuscated examples of course... But if it is, don't you need to get the relevant value? Otherwise what relevant does `cat_id` have to anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is not too big:

```
UPDATE department d
   SET cat_id = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT d2.dname)
                 FROM department d2
                 WHERE d2.dname <= d.dname
                );
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try dense_rank for the inner sql?

```
select dense_rank() over (partition by dname order by dname)
     , dname 
from   department
group by dname
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a simple temporary sequence will do:

```
create sequence my_temp_seq1;

update department set cat_id = my_temp_seq1.nextval;

drop sequence my_temp_seq1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE my_seq start with 1 increment by 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE fixDept
  IS 
    v_next number;
BEGIN
    FOR depts in (SELECT DISTINCT DNAME FROM department)
    LOOP
    v_next := my_seq.nextval;
      UPDATE department  
        SET CAT_ID = v_next 
        WHERE DNAME = depts.DNAME;
    END LOOP;
END fixDept;


EXECUTE fixDept;
```